# How to show an arraylist stored in JSON in a JSP using jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

I am new to using jQuery and I wanted to show the contents of an arraylist stored in a JSON on a JSP using jQuery after clicking a button. I really don't know where to start but I already have a code for storing the list in a JSON but I do not know how to call it on a click of a button and I also do not know how to show the contents of the JSON list using jquery

This is my servlet code (newServlet.java):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String bank = request.getParameter("myvalue");
    CVDAO cvDAO = new CVDAO();
    List<Check_Voucher> cList = ceDAO.getCVonBank(bank);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(cList);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

HTML Code (As of now):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
            //On Edit, SET Time Details
    $('a[name="Test"]').click(function(){
               var value =  $(this).attr('id');
       $.get("newServlet",{myvalue:value}, function(){
                   //what to put here???


       });
    });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="btn btn-default" name="Test" id="BPI">Get Checks</a>

</body>
```

I really do not know how to show the contents of the list stored in the JSON. I appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Comment: To 'call it on click of a button', you'll want to make your button's click handler send an AJAX request to your servlet, then in the callback for the AJAX request you can display the list by selecting a page element with jQuery, maybe a `<ul>`, and then for each list item, append a new `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

first, the callback need a return value

```
$.get("newServlet",{myvalue:value}, function(**data**){
});
```

then, you should transfor the return data into a array, just like:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

last, you can "each" it get every Object.

```
$.get("newServlet",{myvalue:value}, function(**data**){
    JSON.parse(data).each(function(i){
       xxxxxx;
    });
});
```